# Laravel many to many insert each side

Tags: php, laravel

My question is maybe easy but I don't find the proper answer and I don't know if what I do is the right way to do it.

I have an articles and a tags tables with a pivot table on id.

What I try to do is :

- insert article
- insert tags if not exist
- insert relationship

My code is :

```
$tags = [];
        foreach ($request->input('tags') as $key => $value) ;
            $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['nom' => $value]);
            $article->tags()->sync($tag);
        }
```

But it only sync the last tag. And maybe there is a better way than sync on foreach loop ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [eloquent sync method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) states:

> The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table.

Since you're doing this in the `foreach` loop, it will remove all values except the respective tag on each iteration through the loop. You want to instead provide an array of tags and sync at the end.

```
    foreach ($request->input('tags') as $key => $value) ;
        $tags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['nom' => $value])->id;
    }
    $article->tags()->sync($tags);
```

Comment: Oooh right thank ! Do you know if there is a better way to create tags ?

Comment: I'm not really that proficient in Laravel, but this seems like a good way to me.

Comment: I've got an illegal offset error when I tried your code :/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$tags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['nom' => $value])->id;`? The quote from the documentation for `sync()` says `[...] accepts an array of IDs [...]` and currently you are handing it an array of objects.

Comment: @Furya Try again with the `id` as Namoshek mentioned.